# The smallest integer that produces remainders of $2$, $4$,$ 6$ and $1$ when divided by$ 3$, $5$,$ 7$ and $11$ respectively is?

Tags: divisibility

I am finding the Chinese Remainder theorem very complicated, Any other wa to solve this will be really helpful,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As asked there is no answer.  You can subtract $1155$ from any solution and get another.  There are infinitely large negative solutions, so if you consider $-1156$ smaller than $-1$ you can always find a smaller integer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-1$ solves the $3,5,7$ cases, so $-1 \pmod {105}$ will work for those.  Now you just have two moduli to worry about.

Comment: How can i solve the last two equations without using mod?

Comment: You need to use mod, but this has made it much easier.  You can just look through $-1, 104, 209, \ldots$ for one that is $1 \pmod {11}$